In proof that if $f: X\to Y$ is injective and for all $x\in X$, $\kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ is purely inseparable, then $f$ is universally injective
I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Proposition 4.35 and stuck at some statement.

Proposition 4.35. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then $f$ is universally injective if and only if $f$ is injective and for all $x\in X$ the extension $\kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ induced by $f^{\sharp}_x$ is purely inseparable.

Proof ( of the converse ) First note that $f$ is universally injective if and only if for every morphism $Y' \to Y$ and for every point $y' \in Y'$ with image $y$ in $Y$ the fiber $(X\times_Y Y')_{y'} = X_y \otimes_{\kappa(y)}\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y')$ consists of at most one point. We may assume that $X_y$ is non-empty, so by hypothesis $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}} = \operatorname{Spec}K$, where $K\supset \kappa(y)$ is purely inseparable. Note next Proposition :

Proposition 4.34. Let $S$ be a scheme and let $X$ and $Y$ be $S$-schemes. Then the canonical immersions $X_{\operatorname{red}}\to X$ and $Y_{\operatorname{red}}\to Y$ induce an isomorphim
$$ (X_{\operatorname{red}}\times_{S_{\operatorname{red}}}Y_{\operatorname{red}})_{\operatorname{red}}
  = (X_{\operatorname{red}}\times_{S}Y_{\operatorname{red}})_{\operatorname{red}}  \xrightarrow{\text{$\cong$}} (X\times_S Y)_{\operatorname{red}}. $$

( Continuing proof ) ?We therefore may assume by Proposition 4.34 that $Y=\operatorname{Spec}k$ and $X=\operatorname{Spec}K$ where $K\supset k$ is purely inseparable and it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Spec}K \otimes_k k'$ has only one point for an arbitrary field extension $k'$ of $k$. This follows from Corollary B.102 ( We accept this statement ). QED.
I don't understand the bold statement. Why the bold statement is true?
My first attempt is as follows. Since $f :X\to Y$ is injective and $f^{-1}(y) = X_y \neq \emptyset$ ( Why can we assume this? ), $X_y= \{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. And by the assumption,
$ \varphi:=\bar{f^{\sharp}_x} : \kappa(y) \to \kappa(x)$ is purely inseparable. Consider the induced morphism $\varphi^{a} : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \to \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(y)$ between affine schemes. Let $i_x : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \to X$, $i_y : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) \to Y$ be the canonical morphisms.
Then my interlude question is, in this situation,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) @>i_x>> X\\
@V \varphi^{a} V V @VV f V\\
\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) @>>i_y> Y
\end{CD}
forms catesian square? If so, then by the uniqueness of the fiber product up to isomorphism, $X_y \cong \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)$ so that $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}} = (\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x))_{\operatorname{red}} \stackrel{?}{=} \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)$, which is desired.
Correct argument? Or is there any other route to show the bold statement?
Can anyone help?

Since $X_y = \{x\} $ consists of single point, it is irreducible so that $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}}$ is an integral scheme. So $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}}$ is of the form $ \{x\}=(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}} = \operatorname{Spec}A$ for some integral domain $A$. Since $x$ is the generic point of $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}}$, $x$ corresponds to the zero ideal of $A$. Since $x=(0)$ is only prime ideal of $A$, it is maximal ideal of $A$. So there are no other ideals besides $(0)$ and $A$. Since $A$ is integral domain, it is field. So,
$$A= \operatorname{Frac}A=A_{(0)} = \mathcal{O}_{(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}},x} \stackrel{\mathcal{O}_{(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}},x}  \operatorname{ is field}}{=} \mathcal{O}_{(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}},x}/\mathfrak{m}_x =: \kappa(x). $$
So $(X_y)_{\operatorname{red}} = \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)$, and since $\kappa(y) \to \kappa(x)$ is purely inseparable as in the question above, we are done.
